# In Java w/Selenium WebDriver, how to I click link on overlay ad using JavaScript only when ad shows?

Tags: java, selenium

I am a newbie to automation and am trying to automate some websites using Java w/Selenium WebDriver. Users with no cookies are presented an interstitial Ad served via JavaScript that overlays the screen. The Ad has a "Skip this advertisement" link on it to close it and I would like to close that Ad so that I can avoid making the thread sleep for 20 seconds until the ad goes away on its own.

This is the site: http://searchsqlserver.com

I can't seem to access the link using normal findElement techniques and I have been trying with the JavascriptExecutor with no luck.

This is my code (that doesn't work!) to show what I am looking to do:

```
if (Common.isElementPresent(By.id("adx_al"), driver)){          
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(findElement(By.linkText("Skip this advertisement")).click());

//Thread.sleep(20000);
}
```

Comment: Seems like if you use IE, the advertisement never comes up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ad is in an `iframe`. You need to

```
driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.id("adx_ldi1_348897")))
...click() // on your advertisement
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Note you may need to play around with the frame locator, probably to make it more generic.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for pointing me in the right direction! I discovered that the iFrame is named dynamically for different ads so I had to deal with that using a "starts-with". This is my working code:

if (Common.isElementPresent(By.id("adx_al"), driver)){   
   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'adx_ldi1')]")));  
   driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Skip")).click();
   driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        }